# Handle when Spring OAuth ClientDetailsService is throwing exception

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We are using Spring Security OAuth2, version 2.0.6.RELEASE.

To make it work we have successfully overridden `ClientDetailsService` as follows. Now let's say an exception occurs inside of the `ClientDetailsService`:

```
public class CustomClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
        ...
        if(some condition) {
            throw new SomeCustomException();
        }
    ...
```

This exception leads to a 401 being returned to the customer. But we have reasons why we want to return a 400 instead. How can we customize this exception? The normal `@ExceptionHandler` stuff seems to not apply at all to this specific OAuth authentication flow.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: No, I didn't... unfortunately... I believe that because I wrote a very brief, concise question, people believe that I didn't put in any effort, but I actually debugged my way through Spring for a pretty decent amount of time... to no avail.